# ChartJs bar not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

First, I just want to say that I am a programming student and fairly new to all of this, including ChartJs.

I'm working on a program that will display a chart using data extracted from a server. This chart will update automatically every X number of seconds by making requests to the server. I have done before a chart very similar to this one, using basically the same data and in the same way. However, this is a different type of chart and I assume I am missing something or doing something wrong, but I can't quite figure it out.

I would love to leave a working code snippet using the same data, but I can't show the address and key of the server as it is a real one from my company, so instead I will leave the code hiding that specific information and I will also show what responses I get from the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <!--- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSGraph.css">
    <title>Second Graph</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="pageChange" onclick="change_page();">Change Page</button>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="bar-chart-projekt"></canvas>
    </div>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="scriptSGraph.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

```
let barChartProjekt;
let serverData;
let stundenProjekt;
let labelsP;
let newLabelsArray;
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://sample-url.de/'; 
const chart = document.getElementById("bar-chart-projekt"); 

window.onload = function() {

  barChartRender(); // Calling the function that renders the chart
  setInterval(() => {
    // Parsing the JSON file and storing it into a variable (Console.Log() to make sure it works)
    serverData = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
    console.log(serverData);
  
    stundenProjekt = serverData.abzurechnen.nachProjekt.map((s) => {
      return s.second.summe; // Storing the value of total hours from the database in a variable
    });
  
    labelsP = serverData.abzurechnen.nachProjekt.map((p) => {
      return p.first; // Storing the strings of each name of each project
    });
    console.log(stundenProjekt);
    console.log(labelsP);

    barChartRender();
  }, 60000)



};  



let barChartRender = () => {
  
  http.open("GET", url);
  http.setRequestHeader('key', 'sample-key'); 

  http.onload = () => {

    Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

    const data = {
        labels: labelsP,
        datasets: [
          {
            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd"],
            data: stundenProjekt
          }
        ]
      };

      if (barChartProjekt) {
        data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
          barChartProjekt.data.datasets[i].data = ds.data;
          barChartProjekt.labels = newLabelsArray;  
      })
      barChartProjekt.update();
    } else {
      barChartProjekt = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
          plugins: {
          legend: { display: false },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Projekte'
          }
        },
        }
      });

    }
   };
http.send();
};
```

Currently, this is how the chart looks:
[image: Picture of the bar chart]

As you can see, the chart doesn't have any bars, however, as you might be able to see, the numbers at the left are fitting with the variables that I set as data for the chart (I will show this below).

Here is the content of the `stundenProjekt` variable (Taken from the console):

```
[240, 163, 99.75, 48.5, 43.25, 22.75, 14.75, 3.25, 2.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25]
```

And here is the content of the `labelsP` variable (Taken from the console):

```
["nexnet-SB-Cloud", "AUTEC - PSK-System²", "Fritzsche", "nexnet-eBalance", "IfT - Neuentwicklung", "wattform", "Migration", "bmp greengas", "nexnet-SQL-Abfragen über API", "Nord Stadtwerke", "edifact", "SOLVIT", "BürgerGrünStrom", "SOLVCPM", "SOLVEDI", "green city power"]
```

So, I want that the content of `labelsP` is displayed at the bottom, and of course, that the bars are actually displayed based on the information from the `stundenProjekt` variable. I hope I didn't miss any necessary information but let me know if I did! Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

step 1-
download chart js

```
npm install chart.js
```

step 2
copy chart.min.js from
node_modules/chartjs/dist
to where you want it then

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="chart.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He is already including chart.js from a CDN don't need to use npm anymore, also your installation step is wrong see: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Answer (score 0):

What I assume might be happening is that the first time when you initialise the chart it doesn't have any data or labels but the second time you call the method it adds the data but it does not have anywhere to map to since it does not have any labels.

So in your if statement where you update the data you also need to call:

```js
barChartProjekt.labels = newLabelsArray;
```

And after that you call the update method.

On a side note, the reason your legend isn't hidden and there is no title displayed is because the namespaces of those have changed in V3, you need to configure them in `options.plugins.legend` and `options.plugins.title` instead of `options.legend` and `options.title`

Comment: I have edited the post with the changes I've done based on what you said here. It's still not displaying the bars or the labels, so I have feeling I misunderstood you or put things in the wrong place. I initialized `newLabelsArray` at the beginning of the code as otherwise it was undefined, I assume that's what you meant but tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I meant you needed to pass your own variable in which you store the labels, I guess that would be data.labels but I'm not totally sure, so in whatever variable your new labels are you need to pass that to the barChartProjekt.labels and then update

Comment: I guess I'm doing it wrong because it's not working. I have a variable called `labelsP` where I store the strings that I want to use as labels, extracted from the server with a request. That's the one I should be passing? I've tried `barChartProjekt.labels = data.labelsP` `barChartProjekt.labels = data.labels` `barChartProjekt.labels = labelsP` but none of this worked