# Chartjs using array in label field

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am making a simple bar chart using Chartjs 3.x

I make requests to a server to fetch json data and then store certain parts of it into arrays, here is the code for this:

```js
serverData = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
console.log(serverData);

stundenProjekt = serverData.abzurechnen.nachProjekt.map((s) => {
  return s.second.summe;
});

labelsP = serverData.abzurechnen.nachProjekt.map((p) => {
  return p.first;
});
```

I then want to use these arrays in the data and label fields of the chart. I'm using `stundenProjekt` as `data` and it works fine, but when I use `labelsP` as `label` for the chart, it doesn't work. Here is the code of the chart:

```
const data = {
  labels: labelsP,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Projekte',
    data: stundenProjekt,
    backgroundColor: [
      '#f4f40b',
    ],
    borderColor: [
      '#B1B101',
    ],
    borderWidth: 3,
  }]
};

  if (barChartProjekt) {
    data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
      barChartProjekt.data.datasets[i].data = ds.data;
      barChartProjekt.labels = newLabelsArray;  
  })
  barChartProjekt.update();
} else {
  barChartProjekt = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {  
        legend: {
          labels: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 18 
            }
          }
        }
      },
      scales: {
        y: {  
          ticks: {
            color: "white",
            font: {
              size: 18,
            },
            stepSize: 1,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        x: { 
          ticks: {
            color: "white",  
            font: {
              size: 14
            },
            stepSize: 1,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The only workaround I have found is to copy the contents of `labelsP` and paste them in the `label` field. These are the contents of `labelsP` and how I did the workaround:

```
["nexnet-SB-Cloud", "AUTEC - PSK-System²", "Fritzsche", "nexnet-eBalance", "IfT - Neuentwicklung", "wattform", "Migration", "Fahrwerkregelkreis", "bmp greengas", "nexnet-SQL-Abfragen über API", "lambda9", "Nord Stadtwerke", "edifact", "SOLVIT", "BürgerGrünStrom", "SOLVCPM", "lambda captis", "SOLVEDI", "green city power", "max.power"]
```

---

```
const data = {
      labels: ["nexnet-SB-Cloud", "AUTEC - PSK-System²", "Fritzsche", "nexnet-eBalance", "IfT - Neuentwicklung", "wattform", "Migration", "bmp greengas", "Fahrwerkregelkreis", "nexnet-SQL-Abfragen über API", "lambda9", "Nord Stadtwerke", "edifact", "SOLVIT", "BürgerGrünStrom", "SOLVCPM", "lambda captis", "SOLVEDI", "green city power", "max.power"],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Projekte',
        data: stundenProjekt,
        backgroundColor: [
          '#f4f40b',
        ],
        borderColor: [
          '#B1B101',
        ],
        borderWidth: 3,
      }]
    };
```

In this way, the chart works and everything shows up as it should, however, I want to use it as shown in the first snippet of code, as `labelsP` gets updated every some seconds with new data extracted from the server. So, why is it that if I put `labelsP` alone in the `label` field it doesn't work, but if I copy and paste the contents of `labelsP` in the `label` field, it does work?

Comment: did you try to setup a function in the label field instead of fix data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChartJs bar not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69266817/chartjs-bar-not-showing-up)

Comment: @LeeLenalee I'm not sure if it does. That's a post from mine as well where you answered but I still didn't solve that problem on that one. I assume solving that question would also solve this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you add the `labels` to the wrong position in the chart configuration.

> Instead of...

```
barChartProjekt.labels = newLabelsArray;
```

> try this...

```
barChartProjekt.data.labels = newLabelsArray;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but your solution worked, thank you!!